# Splash Screen gradient Color in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-layout, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

How Can I make Splash Screen with gradient colors in flutter?

I use [splash_screen_view: ^3.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/splash_screen_view) and I'm trying to add this code ti its `Container` but it's make an error

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  gradient: RadialGradient(
  radius: 2.5,
  stops: [
   0.0,
   0.50,
  ],
  colors: [
   Color.fromRGBO(7, 71, 99, 1),
   Color.fromRGBO(8, 28, 49, 1),
  ],
 ),
),
```

and another code doesn't work

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  color: const [
  Color.fromRGBO(8, 28, 49, 1),
  Color.fromRGBO(7, 71, 99, 1),
 ]
),
```

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: no errors in log window, it doesn't work only

Comment: but you said it makes an error.  It should be helpful if you give more code.

Answer (score 0):

one option is to generate gradient image for example [here](https://angrytools.com/gradient/image/) and than set it as background image in `pubspec.yaml` config like this:

```
splash_screen_view:
  background_image: "assets/your_gradient_image.png"
```